# When using a switch statement in Javascript with multiple cases, how can I refer to a case?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

So I have some code:

```
var Animal = 'Giraffe';
switch (Animal) {
  case 'Cow':
  case 'Giraffe':
  case 'Dog':
  case 'Pig':
    console.log('This animal will go on Noah\'s Ark.');
    break;
  case 'Dinosaur':
  default:
    console.log('This animal will not.');
}
```

Ideally, I'd like the first console.log to print "This Giraffe will go on Noah's Ark", or whatever the variable Animal happened to be. I want to refer to the case. However, I'm not sure how to write that code. Can someone help?

Comment: In that case you don't need the switch statement, just do `console.log('This '+ Animal+' will go on Noah\'s Ark.');`

Comment: @Erevald - Some animals don't make it to the ark, hence the other part of the `switch`...

Comment: @nnnnnn he said `whatever the variable Animal happened to be`.

Comment: @Erevald - That was in the sentence that started "I'd like the **first** console.log to print...". So the switch structure (or equivalent if/else) is required. (Possibly the second log statement should print the `Animal` too, but the wording of its message is different.)

Answer (score 2):

Just use additional arguments to `log` and `Animal`.

```
console.log('This', Animal, 'will go on Noah\'s Ark.');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a **token** `%s` (***string*** in this case) and than after a comma use your variable:

```js
var Animal = 'Giraffe';
switch (Animal) {
  case 'Cow':
  case 'Giraffe':
  case 'Dog':
  case 'Pig':
    console.log('This %s will go on Noah\'s Ark.', Animal);
    break;
  case 'Dinosaur':
  default:
    console.log('%s will not.', Animal);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use your variable:

```
var Animal = 'Giraffe';
switch (Animal) {
  case 'Cow':
  case 'Giraffe':
  case 'Dog':
  case 'Pig':
    console.log('This ' + Animal + ' will go on Noah\'s Ark.');
    break;
  case 'Dinosaur':
  default:
    console.log('This animal will not.');
}
```

(note: I'm using string concatenation here under the assumption that you may actually want to do something other than use the `console.log` function to do something like this - if you really just want to use `console.log`, it may be more reasonable to use one of the other answers provided)